# how to take a letter and swap it with a number english to l33t

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an English to leet converter for class.

I have no idea how to take one letter and turn it into a number 
ex.  `cow` => `c0w`.

Cannot use `system.out.println` to convert `'o'` into `'0'` 
so far i have

```
public static boolean detect(String mike) {
  int num= Integer.parseInt("0");

  if ("o" == "0" ){
    return num;
  }
}

public static void main (String[] arg) {
  System.out.println(detect( "cow life "));
}
```

Comment: if ("o" == "0") : won't this always be false? like : if (1 == 2)

Answer (score 2):

use String.[replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

```
System.out.println("cow life ".replace('o', '0'));
```

be sure to do it for both upper and lower case.

here's a sample function

```
public static ConvertToLeet(string s)
{
    return s
        .replace(o, 0)
        .replace(O, 0)
        .replace(e, 3)
        .replace(E, 3)
        .replace(a, 4)
        .replace(A, 4);
}
```

Comment: you can just use String's toLowerCase() method and then you don't have to worry about both upper and lower case replace method calls. Only downside is all i's are lower case.

Answer (score 1):

Always use .equals() to compare Strings.

It also doesn't make much sense to actually parse it into an integer, if you're just gonna use it as a string anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to parse for an integer, I think that the best solution would be to simply treat all characters in the string as characters. Create a lookup table of some sort (two strings, parallel array, or maybe a HashMap.

Then, either go char by char and look into the lookup table to see if the original char has a replacement, and if so, replace it. Or, just cycle through all of the mapped items, and replace() the chars in the string with their mapped replacements.

Comment: too complicated for such a simple problem; no need to introduce complex data structures.

Comment: I like that you think that an array is a complex data structure :-)

Comment: @Isaac HashMap<Character, Character>; map.put( 'o', '0' );, etc, is hardly complicated.

Comment: why do u need a hash map?? why should the key need to be hashed?? hashing functions take time ya know...collision detection takes time ya know...and yes I would consider any implementation of hash map a complex data structure...little bit more going on in a hash map then just an array

Comment: 411 y0u h4v3 70 d0 is 100p 7hr0ugh ch4rs 0f s7ring 0nc3 4nd r3p14c3 0n3s 7h47 4r3 n3c33s4ry, why w0u1d y0u w4n7 70 b3 h4shing 47 34ch s73p 0f 7h3 w4y? in 4 14ngu4g3 1ik3 chin3s3 wh3r3 7h3 swich s7473m3n7 w0u1d g37 m3ssy bu7 f0r 5 0r 6 ch4r4c73rs 4 swi7ch s7473m3n7 is much m0r3 4ppr0pri473.

Answer (score 1):

Break into character array then iterate through character array changing chars when necessary.

```
public class Leetify {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(leetify("thE qUick Brown fox jumped Over the laZy CaT"));
    }

    public static String leetify(String s){
        //first make lower case then convert to char array
        char temp[] = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            switch(temp[i]){
            //put in whatever letters you want to change here
            case 'e':
                temp[i] = '3';
                break;
            case 'o':
                temp[i] = '0';
                break;
            case 'l':
                temp[i] = '1';
                break;
            case 't':
                temp[i] = '7';
                break;
            case 'a':
                temp[i] = '4';
                break;
            }
        }
        return new String(temp);
    }

}
```

output: 7h3 quick br0wn f0x jump3d 0v3r 7h3 14zy c47

Comment: b3c4us3 i w4s h31ping s0m30n3 s01v3 4 pr0b13m 0n s74ck 0v3rf10w, i n0w h4v3 7his 1337 7r4ns1470r i m4d3 which c4n 7r4ns1473 4ny s3n73nc3 in70 1337sp34k...pr377y us313ss bu7 wh473v3r.